# jsf pie charts with drill down

Tags: jsf, pie-chart

is there any component in jsf that provides pie charts with drill down facility ?

is it possible with jsf ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try primefaces "interactive charts":

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/interactiveCharts.jsf